# How do I send approver email when a specific Google Form item is answered

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm having trouble with Google Forms/Sheets - and just so you know from the start I'm not much of a coder, and I'm VERY new to working with Apps Script.

I'm trying to make the following happen:

1) Have a user answer a single question on the form
2) If that question is answered, and a value is written to the cell column in the associated Sheet, then automatically send an email to 2 pre-defined approver email addresses
3) If that question is not answered, and no value is written to the cell column, then no email is sent to the 2 approvers

I can make this work if I manually add a value to the appropriate column in the sheet with the script I've included below, but it won't work for me if the value written to the sheet comes directly from the form (which is what I need it to do!).

Below is the code I have written in Script Editor on the Form's Sheet that allows me to manually update the column and have the notifications be sent to the approvers (again, my problem is only that the emails are not sent if the column is updated dynamically from the form). As it is written now, if I manually update Column 5 and/or Column 7 an email is sent to the designated set of approvers.

But again, it will not send the notifications if the Form dynamically updates Column 5 or Column 7.

Please help, I've been stuck on this for days - Thank you!!!

**HERE IS MY CURRENT SCRIPT:**

```
/* 
 * This function sends an email when a specific Google Sheets column is edited
 * The spreadsheets triggers must be set to onEdit for this function to work
 */

function sendNotification() {
    //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1N6dqSXs8hdhCi1vrOGT7I7tD2yDMtgK7BSddMPqmuo0');  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    //Get Active cell
    var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
    var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
    var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
    //Define Notification Details for vars

    var recipients = "joseph@XXXXX.com,jmang@XXXXX.com";
    var recipients1 = "joseph2@XXXXX.com"

    var subject = "NEW SENSITIVE DATA REQUEST REQUIRES APPROVAL";
    var subject1 = "ALERT: SENSITIVE DATA REQUEST";
    var body = ss.getName() + " has been updated.  Visit " + ss.getUrl() + " to view the changes.";

    //Check to see which column will trigger the email - this script sends an email to "var recipients" if 
    //column 5 is updated and sends and email to "var recipients1" when colum 7 is updated.

    if (cellcol == 5) {
        //Send the Email to recipients defined in "var recipients"
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }

    if (cellcol == 7) {
        //Send the Email to recipients defined in "var recipients1"
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipients1, subject1, body);
    }

    //End sendNotification
}
```

This is how my triggers on the Sheet are set:
sendNotification from spread sheet 1) On Change, 2) On Edit, and 3) On FormSubmit

One last thing - my company doesn't allow add-ons, so I have to do this with Apps Script...

Comment: Both a Form and a Sheet can have an "On Form Submit" trigger.  You are showing one function in the question.  I don't understand your explanation of how the triggers are set up.  Do you have the `sendNotification()` function assigned to multiple triggers?

Comment: Hi Sandy - thanks for helping.  Here is what my triggers look like for the project: 
sendNotification     From spreadsheet     On change, On edit, and On form submit

Answer (score 1):

Set separate triggers to separate events;

**for sheet edit event:**

```
function sendNotificationAtEdit(event) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
//get edited range
var range = event.range;
var cellcol = range.getColumn();
var cellrow = range.getRow();

//Define Notification Details for vars
var recipients = "joseph@XXXXX.com,jmang@XXXXX.com";
var recipients1 = "joseph2@XXXXX.com"

var subject = "NEW SENSITIVE DATA REQUEST REQUIRES APPROVAL";
var subject1 = "ALERT: SENSITIVE DATA REQUEST";
var body = ss.getName() + " has been updated.  Visit " + ss.getUrl() + " to view the changes.";

    if (cellcol == 5) {
        //Send the Email to recipients defined in "var recipients"
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }

    if (cellcol == 7) {
        //Send the Email to recipients defined in "var recipients1"
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipients1, subject1, body);
    }

    //End sendNotification
}
```

**for form submit event:**

```
function sendNotificationAtFormSubmit(event) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

//Define Notification Details for vars
var recipients = "joseph@XXXXX.com,jmang@XXXXX.com";
var recipients1 = "joseph2@XXXXX.com"

var subject = "NEW SENSITIVE DATA REQUEST REQUIRES APPROVAL";
var subject1 = "ALERT: SENSITIVE DATA REQUEST";
var body = ss.getName() + " has been updated.  Visit " + ss.getUrl() + " to view the changes.";
//if form submitted 5th question's answer is not empty
    if (event.values[4] !== '') {
        //Send the Email to recipients defined in "var recipients"
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }

    if (event.values[6] !== '') {
        //Send the Email to recipients defined in "var recipients1"
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipients1, subject1, body);
    }

    //End sendNotification
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping!

I've made your changes, but now when I try to run the script I get TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined.

It stops at line 15 which is:  var range = event.range

Comment: And you can't run the script, edit your spreadsheet cell on col 5 and check

Comment: Yes, it still sends the notifications if I edit the spreadsheet directly, but it will not send the notifications when an entry is added to col 5 by answering a question from the form.

Comment: I edited my answer, you need to set separate triggers

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to do what you want, is to check the Form response, NOT the cell in the spreadsheet.  At least not for the On Form Submit trigger.   You may need BOTH, and `onEdit()` trigger, *and* an On Form Submit trigger.

So, in the On Form Submit trigger, you need to get the current Form response, get the Item you need, and then get the individual response from the item that corresponds to column 5 in the spreadsheet.

You could check the last row in the response sheet, and get column 5, and that will work perfectly **IF** you never have lots of people simultaneously submitting Form requests.  In that situation, you need to Lock the document, which you might want to do anyway.

In order to get the last response with the On Submit Trigger, you need to add the "event" object to the function.

```
function sendNotification(e) {
```

Then you need to get the current response:

```
function sendNotification(e) {
  /* Logger.log('e: ' + e);

  for (var key in e) {
    Logger.log('key: ' + key)  
    Logger.log('value: ' + e[key]);
  };  */

  var allAnswers = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var howManyQuestionsInForm = allAnswers.length;
  Logger.log('howManyQuestionsInForm: test again: ' + howManyQuestionsInForm);
  /* for (var key in allAnswers) {
    Logger.log('key: ' + key)  
    Logger.log('value: ' + allAnswers[key]);
  }; */

  var questionThree = allAnswers[2];

  var theAnswerIs = questionThree.getResponse();
  Logger.log('theAnswerIs: ' + theAnswerIs);

  if (theAnswerIs !== "") {
    //Send email
    Logger.log('it got to here')
  };

};
```

[Google Documentation - Form Event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events)

Comment: Sandy - thanks again for trying to help.

So I created a new form with 2 questions.  I'd like to get an email only if question 2 has been answered.  I've tried your code and I changed all references from "Fifth" to "2nd".

Still doesn't work, I have set Spreadsheet on edit, and spreadsheet On form submit triggers on.  Still not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: OK - this sends an email from the form when ANY column is modified, but what should I add to this to have the email send if only 1 column is modified?

function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var lastRowNumber = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
var recipients = "joseph.@xxx.com,ggg@xxx.com";
  var subject = 'xxx';
  var body = ss.getName() + " X " + ss.getUrl() + " X.";
  {
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
}